# How to correctly import task durations from xml to MS Project 2013?

Tags: xml, import, ms-project

can someone give me an example of a XML file which can be imported to MS Project, which would contain one task planned for some period of time and one resource? I currently have this following XML, MS Project imports it without any error, but the schedule becomes all messed up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
     <SaveVersion>14</SaveVersion>
     <Name>Projekt1.xml</Name>
     <ScheduleFromStart>1</ScheduleFromStart>
     <Tasks>
          <Task>
               <UID>1</UID>
               <ID>1</ID>
               <Name>Test task</Name>
               <Active>1</Active>
               <Manual>0</Manual>
               <Type>0</Type>
               <Start>2018-06-21T09:00:00</Start>
               <Finish>2018-07-06T18:00:00</Finish>
          </Task>
     </Tasks>
     <Resources>
          <Resource>
              <UID>0</UID>
              <ID>0</ID>
              <Type>1</Type>
          </Resource>
          <Resource>
              <UID>1</UID>
              <ID>1</ID>
              <Name>Test resource</Name>
              <Type>1</Type>
          </Resource>
      </Resources>
      <Assignments>
          <Assignment>
              <UID>2</UID>
              <TaskUID>1</TaskUID>
              <ResourceUID>1</ResourceUID>
          </Assignment>
     </Assignments>
</Project>
```

When I import this to MS Project, it doesn't import the Start and Finish dates from the task and sets the duration to "0 days?".

Why is that? Is there something missing (maybe a definition of calendar or some additional attributes of the task or assignment to resource?)

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal working file for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
    <ScheduleFromStart>1</ScheduleFromStart>
    <StartDate>2018-06-21T08:00:00</StartDate>
    <ProjectExternallyEdited>0</ProjectExternallyEdited>

    <Tasks>
        <Task>
            <UID>1</UID>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Test task</Name>
            <IsNull>0</IsNull>
            <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
            <Start>2018-06-21T08:00:00</Start>
            <Finish>2018-07-06T17:00:00</Finish>
            <Duration>PT96H0M0S</Duration>
            <DurationFormat>7</DurationFormat>
            <Work>PT96H0M0S</Work>
            <RemainingWork>PT96H0M0S</RemainingWork>
        </Task>
    </Tasks>

    <Resources>
        <Resource>
            <UID>1</UID>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Test Resource</Name>
            <Type>1</Type>
        </Resource>
    </Resources>

    <Assignments>
        <Assignment>
            <TaskUID>1</TaskUID>
            <ResourceUID>1</ResourceUID>
            <RemainingWork>PT96H0M0S</RemainingWork>
            <Work>PT96H0M0S</Work>
        </Assignment>
    </Assignments>
</Project>
```

MS Project can be quite specific about what it wants to see in an XML file to get the results you are after. There are a few odd settings required (for example, `ProjectExternallyEdited`, `IsNull` and so on) but the main difference is that I've specified the amount of work on both the task and the resource assignment.

If you are generating this file programatically you may find [MPXJ](http://mpxj.org) helpful.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks very much for the answer! With your example it's working fine, but for some reason when I use it for multiple tasks with different scheduled dates, Project changes all start dates to the project StartDate. I've tried to remove the ScheduleFromStart element and fiddle with the data but I can't seem to make it so that every task started in different date&time. Do you have any ideas here?

Comment: I think if there are no constraints (i.e. the tasks are not linked to each other as predecessors and successors, the resources aren't levelled, and there is no constraint date/type on the task) then the default behaviour will be to schedule everything as early as possible.

Comment: Oh, ok. So maybe I need to figure out a way to generate these constraints. Thanks for the hint. And also thanks for the MPXJ link, I know about that and it would help a lot, sadly I'm not able to use it due to several technical limitations of my infrastructure, so I'm stuck with having to do this manually..